# What is the correct statement of the infinitary associativity law?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $X$ denote a non-empty set. Write $\mathcal{L}$ for the class of all ordered pairs $(L,f)$ where:

1. $L$ is a linear poset (possibly empty), and
2. $f$ is an arbitrary function $L \rightarrow X.$

Then $\mathcal{L}$ forms a "complete monoid." What I mean by this is that firstly, we can take products of infinitely many elements. In particular, for any linear poset $I$ and any family $\lambda:I \rightarrow\mathcal{L}$, write $\prod_{i \in I} \lambda_i$ for the concatenation of all the $\lambda_i$'s in the order determined by $\lambda$ and $I$. Secondly, (possibly) infinite products clearly satisfy some kind of infinitary associativity law. It should be of the form:

$$\prod_{i \in I}\prod_{j \in J(i)}(\lambda_i)_j = \prod_{\mathrm{something}}\mathrm{something}$$

Where:

1. $I$ is an arbitrary linear poset
2. $J(i)$ is a linear poset dependent on $i \in I$
3. $(\lambda_i)_j$ is an element of $\cal L$ dependent on $i \in I$ and $j \in J(i)$.

Anyway, I'm having trouble writing down this law correctly.

> **Question.** What is the correct statement of the infinitary associativity law?

Comment: What you're looking after is a general associativity *and* commutativity law. Try $\prod_i J(i)$ as the index set.

Comment: When you write \Pi_{i\in I} instead of \prod_{i\in I}, you see $\displaystyle\Pi_{i\in I}$ instead of $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in I}$ in a displayed context, and $\Pi_{i\in I}$ instead of $\prod_{i\in I}$ in an inline context.  The latter usage is standard and I edited the question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thanks, that looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the ordered sum of a poset-indexed family of posets!

The ordered sum of such a family $J = \{J(i)\}_{i \in I}$, which I shall denote by either $\bigoplus J$ or $\bigoplus_{i \in I} J(i)$, is the poset whose underlying set is

$$\bigoplus_{i \in I}J(i) = \{(i ,j)\mid i \in I \text{ and } j \in J(i)\}$$

and whose ordering $\le_{\oplus J}$ is defined lexicographically such that

$$(i, j) \le_{\bigoplus J} (k, l) \iff (i <_I k) \text{ or } (i = k \text{ and } j \le_{J(i)} l) $$

When $I$ is a linear poset and when each $J(i)$ is a linear poset, it is possible to verify that $\bigoplus J$ is a linear poset. In this case,

$$\prod_{i \in I}\prod_{j \in J(i)} (\lambda_i)_j = \prod_{(i, j) \in \bigoplus J} (\lambda_i)_j$$

### Edit:

Note that the underlying set of $\bigoplus J$ is the set coproduct of the underlying sets of each $J(i)$. However, $\bigoplus J$ is *not* a poset coproduct of each $J(i)$.

Comment: A small comment: better not to call this the coproduct, since it does not satisfy the universal property of coproducts. For what its worth, I have heard it called the "ordered sum".

Comment: @goblin Ahh, you are correct. I've clarified the answer using the "ordered sum", and I've added a small section about set coproduct vs. poset coproduct.